# Why do Zabbix and docker metrics differ?

Tags: docker, zabbix

I'm using the Docker template on Zabbix 5.0 LTS and I get different values on item "Container /server-web-reporting-1: Memory usage" than of docker stats.

With zabbix:

```
zabbix_get -s dockerhost -k docker.container_stats["/web-reporting-1"] | grep -o "memory.*stats"
memory_stats":{"usage":9817108480,"max_usage":10882347008,"stats
```

With docker stats:

```
docker stats --no-stream web-reporting-1
CONTAINER ID   NAME                     CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT    MEM %     NET I/O   BLOCK I/O        PIDS
801396c54212   web-reporting-1   14.03%    5.24GiB / 11.58GiB   45.27%    0B / 0B   306GB / 11.8GB   25
```

Why does difference occur?